# How to import editor/IDE settings to XE7 from an earlier version

Tags: delphi-xe3, delphi-xe7, c++builder-xe7, c++builder-xe3

There does not seem to be any mechanism to export colour/tab spacing/code completion options, etc., from an earlier version of RAD Studio (in my case XE3) to the current XE7.

It would be really nice to not have to go through the options one-by-one to make sure they are the same...

I've searched the 'net and help files without finding anything related to this.

Comment: You can sometimes export the registry key from the older version (just the part containing the editor settings), edit the resulting .reg file to reflect the new version's location, and then import the .reg file. Be sure to export the entire registry key for the new version first as a backup before trying, of course. If something goes wrong, you can then just delete the registry key entirely and import it back in from the one you exported.

Comment: @KenWhite This suggestion might do the trick, but it's pretty cumbersome. With new versions being released every year, you would think that there is some easier mechanism to migrate "favourite" setting.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't. This is the only way I've been able to do it without manually reconfiguring things every time. Feel free to post a request at the EMBT Delphi forums for a new feature to do so, but it's been done before to no avail.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks. Maybe I'll take my request to EMBT. There are several other improvements to the IDE that I can think of (e.g., an "X" button on the file tabs to make closing them easier, and the same for multiple search results)

Comment: @EBlake I believe that XE8 now has this facility.  I have not used it yet.  I will let you know in a few days time.

Comment: @RohitGupta I was that announcement too. I wonder if it can be used between versions other than XE8. Due to a requirement to maintain XP support, we still use XE3 as well as XE7. Have not upgraded third-party components to XE8.